# ASP.Net Core 3 and simple POST the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to POST to an ASP.NET core 3 server.
However my `number` is always `0`.
Is there a trick in the ASP.Net Core 3 that I don't understand?

The parameter `[FromBody]` does not solve the problem. And the classes as parameter don't help, The values don't change.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/add")]
public ActionResult<Dictionary<string, object>> Add(int number)
{

    // number is always 0 :(  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    number += 1;

    var d = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["message"] = "Hello",
        ["number"] = number 
    };

    return Ok(d);
}
```

```
let input = { number: 5825 }

$.ajax(
    {
        url: `/api/add`,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(input),
        accepts: "application/json",
        complete: function (output) {
            // completed
        }
    }
);
```

My services are

```
services.AddSession();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

And i use

```
app.UseSession();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); });
```

Comment: `let input = { number: 0 }` you are setting it to be 0.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to change the number. But obviously that doesnt solve the problem (:

Comment: Posting complex type to bind to a simple type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on shown client code, that client is posting complex type to bind to a simple type on the server.

Create a model

```
public class Data {
    public int number { get; set; }
}
```

Bind the model to the action

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/add")]
public IActionResult Add([FromBody]Data model) {

    if(ModelState.IsValid) {

        var number = model.number;
        number += 1;

        var d = new {
            message = "Hello",
            number = number 
        };

        return Ok(d);
    }

    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript, instead of posting the object input, try posting the number variable directly:

```
let number=5825;

$.ajax(
    {
        url: `/api/add`,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: number,
        accepts: "application/json",
        complete: function (output) {
            // completed
        }
    }
);
```

In your controller use [FromBody] annotation:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/add")]
public ActionResult<Dictionary<string, object>> Add([FromBody]int number)
{

    // number is always 0 :(  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    number += 1;

    var d = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["message"] = "Hello",
        ["number"] = number 
    };

    return Ok(d);
}
```

I agree the issue is that you are trying to send a complex Type while your action is only accepting simple type int. Let me know if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow @Nkosi's solution to add the property to the model.Or if you do not want to create a model,just add the number to url query like below:

```
let number = 5825;
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/api/add?number=' + number,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            accepts: "application/json",
            complete: function (output) {
                // completed
            }
        }
    );


[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/add")]

public ActionResult<Dictionary<string, object>> Add(int number)
{
  //...
}
```